# Adding jar to android application

Tags: android, jar, android-library

what is the differnce between:

1. Adding jar files to libs folder by dragging to it
2. Adding jar files via Java Build Path -> Libraries
3. Adding them in Order and Export tab

Some times I just drag jars to libs folder and projects works fine, and sometimes I need also add them in Libraries tab to get project to work.

Comment: adding jar to projects libs folder will add it to your build path automatically. what is the problem?

Comment: Nope, I do not see them in the build path

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707024/android-eclipse-put-jar-in-libadd-to-build-path-vs-put-jar-in-libs. check commonsware answer. It may be a library project cross check again.