# android import jar encounter NoClassDefFound

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I encountered NoClassDefFound when my app is running, as I have imported sth form a external jar file. The file is located in /libs and has been added to the java build path. I use Eclipse with android SDK. I have tried clean for many times.

Comment: Its not added to build path. Also which external jar are you using? Need more info

Comment: @Raghunandan  I use httpmime. it has been added to the java build path in the properties of the projuect

Comment: Just Add the jar to libs folder. Clean and Build your project once

Comment: Restarting eclipse also works sometimes. Eclipse still show some bugs while updating dependencies. Restarting works in these cases

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
1. Your Project -> right click -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Jar -> yourjar.jar
2. Your Project -> right click -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order & Export --> Select All --> OK
```

Comment: Adding jar to libs folder will automatically add it to build path. Reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707024/android-eclipse-put-jar-in-libadd-to-build-path-vs-put-jar-in-libs

Answer (score 0):

Try adding lib to build path. Right click your lib in eclipse and add to build path.

Or 
go to projects properties in eclipse and in java - > java build path -> order and export ,just tick check box on your lib.

**Update ::** now just uninstall your app from device and clean and build project and run. (clean all projects if you have imported others)..... also build any other library project in eclipse if you have used it in your project.

[image: reference image]

Comment: All item in this page has been checked.

Comment: now just uninstall your app from device and clean and build project and run. (clean all projects if you have imported others)..... also build any other library project in eclipse if you have used it in your project.

Comment: give up if ans was helpfull.