# how to fix android.support.v4.view.pageTitleStrip in Tab?

Tags: android, tabs

I am beginner in android development. I am trying a scroll tab by using eclipse with the help of a tutorial video tutorial .I used page viewer and fragmentActivity and I am getting an error that

> android.support.v4.view.pageTitleStrip

the above class could not be found.

Comment: you need to add `support-v4 lib` in your project.

Comment: hw to add.. i gave fix build path then android build path dialog box opened then i click android private library and update but its not updating.. help me

Comment: go to this [https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a `Support Library` without resources to your application project:

1. Make sure you have downloaded the Android Support Library using the **SDK Manager**.
2. Create a `libs/` directory in the root of your application project.
3. Copy the **JAR** file from your `Android SDK` installation directory (e.g., `<sdk>/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar`) into your application's project `libs/` directory.
4. Right click the JAR file and select **Build Path > Add to Build Path**.

Go to this for more information https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: when you add it to libs folder the jar will be automatically added to build path

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707024/android-eclipse-put-jar-in-libadd-to-build-path-vs-put-jar-in-libs.